# Why do algorithms text book uses "nondecreasing" instead of "increasing" to mention sorted array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there any particular reason? or it's just the preference of author? 
For example here's the Kruskal algorithm from CLRS:

[image: Kruskal's algorithm]

Comment: This is a good question - if it was text rather than a picture.  Key words of the picture are not findable via a search.  Suggest editing to text.

Comment: I think nondecreasing is not the same as increasing. Nondecreasing covers the values of same sorting weight as well.

Comment: It's the difference between greater-than and greater-than-or-equals.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302423/monotonically-increasing-vs-non-decreasing

Comment: @samgak thanks! interesting example from link : 0,1,−1,2,−2,3,−3,…0,1,−1,2,−2,3,−3,…  is all of "not increasing", "not decreasing" and "not constant"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nondecreasing means that the values could stay the same - they don't decrease but they could increase or stay the same.

The values 1, 1, 1, 2 are in nondecreasing order but 1, 2, 3, 4 are increasing.

Comment: +1. FWIW, I don't think "increasing" is *necessarily* stricter than "nondecreasing"; rather, it's just that "increasing" is ambiguous between "nondecreasing" and "strictly increasing". "Nondecreasing" avoids the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Nondecreasing is a strictly weaker requirement. If the algorithm said 'increasing' instead of 'nondecreasing' it would be impossible to order the edges if they had any repeated weights.

Note that I am interpreting *increasing* as x(n) < x(n + 1), i.e. as strictly increasing.

Answer (score -1):

The term "nondecreasing" is used in the context of a sorted array to allow for repeated values. In a sorted array, the elements are arranged in ascending order, but there may be repeated elements.

Using the term "increasing" to describe a sorted array implies that the elements are strictly increasing, meaning that there are no repeated values. However, this is not always the case in a sorted array. For example, the array [1, 2, 2, 3, 4] is sorted, but it is not strictly increasing.

Therefore, the term "nondecreasing" is used to describe a sorted array where the elements may remain the same or increase. This term is more general and inclusive than "increasing" and accurately describes the properties of a sorted array, whether or not it contains repeated values.